Why is the wallet address constantly invalid?
This is an API with endpoints GET /price and GET /balance the architecture flow is as follows:
actor User
User -> ExpressAPI : Request Token Balance / Price
ExpressAPI -> Redis : Check Cache
alt Cache Hit
Redis --> ExpressAPI : Return Cached Data
else Cache Miss
ExpressAPI -> BlockchainInteraction : Get Token Balance
ExpressAPI -> PriceOracleAPI : Get Token Price
BlockchainInteraction --> ExpressAPI : Token Balance
PriceOracleAPI --> ExpressAPI : Token Price
ExpressAPI -> Redis : Cache Balance & Price
end
ExpressAPI -> User : Return Response
Whenever I fetch token balance: http://localhost:3000/balance?walletAddress=&tokenAddress=
I get this error:
`curl : {"success":false,"message":"Error fetching token balances","er
ror":"bad address checksum (argument=\"address\", value=\"0xd93a53B5F
382F2a51A4AE3879ABC8F789Bd60e6b\", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=add
ress/5.7.0)"}
At line:1 char:1
+ curl "http://localhost:3000/token-balance/0xd93a53B5F382F2a51A4AE38
79 ...`

And also the server says:
reason: 'bad address checksum',
code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
argument: 'address',
value: '0xd93a53B5F382F2a51A4AE3879ABC8F789Bd60e6b'
Here are the files
tokenBalances.js
import { Alchemy, Network } from "alchemy-sdk";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

const config = {
  apiKey: process.env.ALCHEMY_API,
  network: Network.ETH_MAINNET,
};
const alchemy = new Alchemy(config);

const tokenContractAddresses = ["0x4838b106fce9647bdf1e7877bf73ce8b0bad5f97"];

async function getTokenBalances(req, res) {
  const ownerAddress = req.params.ownerAddress;
  const tokenAddress = req.params.tokenAddress || tokenContractAddresses;
  console.log("Received request for owner address:", ownerAddress,"and token address:", tokenAddress);
  try {
    const data = await alchemy.core.getTokenBalances(ownerAddress, tokenAddress);
    console.log(`Token balance for address ${ownerAddress}:`, data);
    res.json({
      success: true,
      message: `Token balance for address ${ownerAddress}`,
      data: data
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching token balances:", error);
    res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      message: "Error fetching token balances",
      error: error.message
    });
  }
}

export default getTokenBalances;

tokenRoutes.js
import express from "express";
import getTokenBalances from '../tokenBalances.js';

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/token-balance/:ownerAddress/:tokenAddress", getTokenBalances);

export default router;

server.js
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import 'dotenv/config';
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import express from 'express';
import tokenRoutes from "./routes/tokenRoutes.js";
import Redis from 'ioredis';

dotenv.config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Configure Redis connection
const redis = new Redis({
  host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
  port: process.env.REDIS_PORT
});

app.use(express.json());
app.use('/', tokenRoutes);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});

export default app;


There is a standard for checksummed addresses that also includes the chain ID:
https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1191
Basically, the chain ID is prepended to the address hex, e.g. toChecksum, which produces different checksums for different chains to help prevent mistakes in cross-chain transfers.
After a quick brute-force check, I discovered that the address 0xd93a53B5F382F2a51A4AE3879ABC8F789Bd60e6b is checksummed for chain ID 57245, but you are trying to submit this to the Mainnet with chain ID 1, which is causing the failure. To work around this, you can a) lowercase the address before checking the balance, b) ensure it is checksummed for the correct chain ID, or c) use the older checksum format that does not include the chain ID.

Wow, that's a great explanation! I wasn't aware about the chain ID role in the checksummed address. Can you please tell how to get the checksummed address depending on the chain ID using some library like ethers.js or web3.js?

Hi @SYEDASADKAZMI I know viem supports the chainId: https://viem.sh/docs/utilities/getAddress.html

Noted. Thanks for sharing!
